# c++ passing arrays in constructor without defining them elsewhere

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I currently have this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AddressInfo.h"

AddressInfo::AddressInfo(int ammoCount, int pointerLevel, DWORD baseAddress, DWORD* offsetArray) {
    ammo = ammoCount;
    numPointers = pointerLevel;
    this->baseAddress = baseAddress;
    offsets = (DWORD*)malloc(sizeof(offsetArray));
    this->offsets = offsetArray;
};

AddressInfo::~AddressInfo() {
    delete[] offsets;
}

void AddressInfo::print() {
    std::cout << this->offsets[0]<< std::endl;
}





DWORD x[] = { 0x374, 0x14, 0x0 };
AddressInfo* ammo = new AddressInfo(1000, 3, (DWORD)(0x00509B74), x);

int main()
{
    ammo->print();
    system("pause");
}
```

This code works, but I want to do the following:
Instead of pre-defining the array and passing it into the constructor, I want to pass the array in as follows: {0x374,0x14,0x0}

Is this possible / is this practical

I tried typecasting: (DWORD*) {0x374,0x14,0x0}

Comment: The `{ x, y, ...}` notation is only useful when assigning. I don't think it can be used in a function call.

Comment: use a `std::vector`.

Comment: If you are using C, this could be a compound literal.

Comment: `offsets = (DWORD*)malloc(sizeof(offsetArray));` combined with `delete[] offsets;` simply cannot work

Comment: @UnholySheep the assignment `this->offsets = offsetArray` breaks it before it can even get to that.

Comment: sorry I didn't have that before, I was just fooling around trying to figure stuff out. I'm new to c++

Answer (score 3):

You should use `std::vector` for this task and for future tasks. Look how easy and clean it makes everything

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class AddressInfo
{
    int ammoCount;
    int pointerLevel;
    std::vector<uint32_t> offsets;

public:
    AddressInfo(int ammoCount, int pointerLevel, std::vector<uint32_t> offsets) :
        ammoCount{ ammoCount }, pointerLevel{ pointerLevel }, offsets{ offsets }
    {   
    }

    void print(size_t i) 
    {
        std::cout << this->offsets.at(i) << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    AddressInfo ammo (1000, 0x00509B74, { 0x374, 0x14, 0x0 });
    ammo.print(0);
    ammo.print(1);
    ammo.print(2);

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/WaLiP8

Answer (score 3):

This constructor is just wrong

```
AddressInfo::AddressInfo(
  int ammoCount, 
  int pointerLevel, 
  DWORD baseAddress, 
  DWORD* offsetArray) 
{
  ammo = ammoCount;
  numPointers = pointerLevel;
  this->baseAddress = baseAddress;
  offsets = (DWORD*)malloc(sizeof(offsetArray));
  this->offsets = offsetArray;
};
```

first you allocate using malloc, in C++ we usually use new since malloc does not call any constructors. second sizeof doesn't give the size of the array, it gives you the size of the pointer - it is the same as writing sizeof(DWORD*)

then after you allocated something for `offsets` to point to,  you then let it point to the parameter so what bytes you allocated with malloc are leaked.

In your destructor you assume that `offsetArray` has previously been allocated with new[] and passed to the constructor but how will a user of your class know that?

Imagine somebody creating your AddressInfo using an array allocated on the stack.

```
DWORD myArray[10];
AddressInfo adr = new AddressInfo(ammoCount,pointerLevel,baseAddress,offsetArray);
```

People do not want to look into the implementation to look for assumptions, that is the whole idea of putting stuff in a class, to hide the implementation.

Instead use `std::array` or `std::vector` when you work with arrays in C++, you then create a much more transparent and clean design - see Kilzone Kids answer.